# No boot. Error file /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic not found

Tags: boot

I accidentally deleted files in the boot directory and now the system cannot boot anymore.
Is it possible to restore the boot directory and especially the file /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic ?

I saw a similar problem here :
[System doesn't boot anymore. Error: file initrd.img-3.11.0-20-generic not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465826/system-doesnt-boot-anymore-error-file-initrd-img-3-11-0-20-generic-not-found)

The solution would be to mount the local partition in a live environment and re-install the files. As I am a real newbie (as you can see from my problem itself) I have difficulties to adjust the solution to my specific case.

I have access to my computer from a live USB and the result of

```
sudo blkid
```

is

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="BD1B-FB3E" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="ad8e18f0-dccd-4aa6-acbe-b3db9f5634a3" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="b8b1b2fc-cebb-4bb7-8739-899147dcd776" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="CDC9-DC5D" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="E6A3-F52D" TYPE="vfat"
```

Do you know if it is possible to restore the files or, if not, to save my data (which is not on a specific partition as it should be...) ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edit :
I use a version of Linux Mint. Response to `lsb_release --all` is

```
    LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-
3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-
4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-
4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 16 Petra
Release:    16
Codename:   petra
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the live USB mount your root partition:

`$ sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu`

`$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/ubuntu`

Type the following to allow DNS resolution from within the chroot:

`$ sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/ubuntu/etc/resolv.conf`

Mount proc filesystem

`$ sudo mount -o bind /proc /mnt/ubuntu/proc`

Now chroot to that installation:

`$ sudo chroot /mnt/ubuntu /bin/bash`

Reinstall kernel image package (that should also trigger grub-update):

`(chroot)$ apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic`

If it will not trigger kernel upgrade, then (still in chroot):

`(chroot)$ update-grub`

Exit chroot with Ctrl+d.
Reboot system without live USB.

Comment: There is no package `kernel-image`.

Comment: changed to `linux-image-generic`, actually reinstall might be impossible, so if  it wont work, just use `apt-get install linux-image-generic`

Comment: In both cases the response is : 'Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-image-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-image-generic' has no installation candidate
'

Comment: do `apt-get update` first :)

Comment: Same thing after an apt-get update. But the apt-get update displayed a lot of error messages (this was an other problem I had before) : `E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use? Please paste output os `lsb_release --all` Did you upgraded to newer Ubuntu version? And also post content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I added my LSB release in the first post (I am on Linux Mint). for `/etc/apt/sources.list`, the answer is `bash: /etc/apt/sources/list: No such file or directory`

Comment: Look closer at error message :)

Comment: :) Sorry... New error : `bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied`

Comment: Do it within chrooted environment (after you did `chroot command`).

Comment: I see you might have problem with it anyway ... Linux mint 16 is no longer supported - http://www.linuxmint.com/download_all.php
I'd just reinstall newer version, since I'm not sure if version upgrade will work on 'slightly' damaged system.
I have one more idea - paste output of `ls -1 /var/cache/apt/archives` - if you did not do apt-get clean after installing kernel, then there is a hope of using deb package from cache.

Comment: I was already within chrooted environment. If I am not, I have also Permission denied, and if I try with sudo (in chroot), i have : `sudo: unable to resolve host mint
sudo: /etc/apt/sources.list: command not found`

Comment: Output of archives gives : `lock
partial`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I will see what I can do to reinstall newer version without deleting my data :) I knew this would happen one day...

Comment: Have fun:) You can try one more thing http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/06/how-to-upgrade-to-linux-mint-17-qiana-from-linux-mint-16-petra.html - it just looks like a lot of content, but in fact there is only a handful of commands you need to execute there.

Comment: in my case `update-grub` gives `grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)` and I have to `mount dev` to make it work